# Yemeni Rial exchange in Istanbul

Tags: money, exchange, istanbul, yemen

Can I exchange Yemeni Rial into US dollars at the airport in Istanbul at any of the currency exchange desks?

I work in Yemen and have a bunch of leftover local notes that I would like to exchange into US dollars.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't exchange them in Yemen?  You would almost certainly get the best rates there, since the Yemeni rial is a very minor currency.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Central Bank of Turkey](http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/wps/wcm/connect/tcmb+tr/tcmb+tr/main+page+site+area/bugun), the following currencies are commonly exchanged in banks:

> USD, AUD, DKK, EUR, GBP, CHF, SEK, CAD, KWD, NOK, SAR, JPY, BGN, RON,
>   RUB, IRR, CNY, PKR

Therefore it is unlikely that you would be able to exchange Yemeni rial (YER) anywhere in Turkey.